Arch linux: Cannot install R package "ragg"
After 10+ years using debian-based linux, I am now using Arch.
I use R for data science analysis and development. I am facing difficulties to install the R package ragg (r-ragg), which is a dependency for other libraries I use.  When I try to install "ragg" from within R using the install.packages("ragg") command, I get the following error:
make: * [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:204: agg/src/agg_font_freetype.o] Error 1

which leads to a compilation failure for "ragg".
I got the same error message in Arch and in an arch-based OS
Any suggestion to resolve this? (I have search a lot how to solve this, without concrete success.)
I also tried to install it via terminal using yay -S r-ragg and I received this as feedback:
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:204: agg/src/agg_font_freetype.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ragg’
removing ‘/home/machiavelli/.cache/yay/r-ragg/src/build/ragg’
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
Aborting...
-> error making: r-ragg-exit status 4
-> Failed to install the following packages. Manual intervention is required:
r-ragg - exit status 4

The relevant part of the Makeconf file is:
$ awk 'NR>200 && NR<210' /usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf 
.cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.cc.d:
    @echo "making $@ from $<"
    @$(CXX) -M $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< > $@
.cpp.d:
    @echo "making $@ from $<"

Lie 204 is the .cpp.o section.

@marcus-müller requested further output. Here is what is printed in the R console:
> install.packages("ragg")

* installing *source* package ‘ragg’ ...
** package ‘ragg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/sysprof-6 -pthread
Using PKG_LIBS=-lfreetype -lpng16 -ltiff -ljpeg
** libs
using C++ compiler: ‘g++ (GCC) 14.2.1 20240805’

[endless compilation verbose here]

agg/src/agg_font_freetype.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bool agg::decompose_ft_outline(const FT_Outline&, bool, const trans_affine&, PathStorage&) [with PathStorage = path_storage_integer<int, 6>; FT_Outline = FT_Outline_]’:
agg/src/agg_font_freetype.cpp:1071:48:   required from here
 1071 |                         if(decompose_ft_outline(m_cur_face->glyph->outline,
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1072 |                                                 m_flip_y,
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
 1073 |                                                 m_affine,
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
 1074 |                                                 m_path32))
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
agg/src/agg_font_freetype.cpp:182:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
  182 |             tags  = outline.tags  + first;
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
      |                                   |
      |                                   unsigned char*
agg/src/agg_font_freetype.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bool agg::decompose_ft_outline(const FT_Outline&, bool, const trans_affine&, PathStorage&) [with PathStorage = path_storage_integer<short int, 6>; FT_Outline = FT_Outline_]’:
agg/src/agg_font_freetype.cpp:1092:48:   required from here
 1092 |                         if(decompose_ft_outline(m_cur_face->glyph->outline,
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1093 |                                                 m_flip_y,
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
 1094 |                                                 m_affine,
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
 1095 |                                                 m_path16))
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
agg/src/agg_font_freetype.cpp:182:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
  182 |             tags  = outline.tags  + first;
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
      |                                   |
      |                                   unsigned char*
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:204: agg/src/agg_font_freetype.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ragg’


ISSUE RESOLVED
install.packages("ragg") downloads and installs (or fails to install, in my case) ragg version 1.3.2 from CRAN. This was not working on my workstation running arch-based Endeavour OS.
I found the source code for ragg version 1.3.2.9000 at [https://r-lib.r-universe.dev/ragg]1 and it worked like a charm. No compilation needed, instant success. I loaded the library and ran a test code and it produced the expected output.
Case closed. Many thanks for your support through this!

the relevant information on why this step fails is probably  a bit above.

Please also include the exact command you used within R. Was this install.packages("ragg") or something else?

Yes, I used install.packages("ragg") as this is the usual way to install packages in R. I clarified my post and added novel information there. Thanks!

was that the whole log? Because, as said, the relevant part is before the final make error.

I can't reproduce this on my Arch, unfortunately. I just ran install.packages("ragg") from an R shell and it worked fine. I also added the line from /usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf that trigger the error. Please check and confirm those are the same on your system (they almost certainly are). Is there really nothing else relevant in the lines before the error? The error mentions agg_font_freetype, could it be that you need to install a freetype font library (complete shot in the dark)? Does running sudo pacman -S freetype2 and then trying to install ragg help?

@terdon freetype2 was already installed. below I pasted the relevant part of Makeconf (line 204), but it reads just like your output:
$(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

Ah well, it was a long shot. Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting for help on formatting your posts.

Thanks for the reference @terdon.
